# jquery sortable droponempty fix

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working with jQuery's sortable (jQuery ui)

By default `dropOnEmpty = true`, and as a *speedup* I'm applying the `connectwith` *after* I apply `.sortable()` to my selectors as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $('#selector1').sortable({ 
    over: function(ev,ui){
      console.log('Dragging over: '+$j(ui.placeholder).parent().parent().parent().attr('id'));
    } 
  )};  
  $('#selector2').sortable({ 
    over: function(ev,ui){
      console.log('Dragging over: '+$j(ui.placeholder).parent().parent().parent().attr('id'));
    } 
  )};

  $('.ui-sortable').sortable('option', connectWith', '.ui-sortable');
</script>
```

I've demonstrated my *logging* to try to figure out what's going on - Imagine I first drag from #selector1 to #selector2 (which is empty) - no logging appears, but than if I drag back into the source, I get the logging, and than when I drag back into the target column it works?

The empty selector even has `ui-sortable` class but it's not connecting!

How should I make sure that even the empty lists while applying the connect-with after initializing the the `connectWith` separately?

Comment: Is that missing `'` on the last line in your original code?

Comment: that's just `pseudocode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/MMyP3/5/

**EDIT:** Code as requested:

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="display:inline">
<div id="column1" class="column">

<div class="element">Element 1</div>
<div class="element">Element 4</div>

</div>

<div id="column2" class="column">

<div class="element">Element 2</div>
<div class="element">Element 3</div>

</div>

<div id="column3" class="column">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column{
    border: 1px solid #E9EAEA;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    min-width:100px;
    padding: 5px;  
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}

.element{
    border: 1px solid #E9EAEA;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; 
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.column').sortable({
    var $this = $(this);
    activate: function(en, ui) {
        $this.css('min-height', '100px');
        $this.css('background-color', '#666');
    },
    deactivate: function(en, ui) {
        $this.css('min-height', '0px');
        $this.css('background-color', '#FFF');
    },
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight'
});

$('.column').sortable('option', 'connectWith', '.column');​
```

**Edit:** I updated my link, I think the main issue was your html structure which I adjusted, also make sure you are dragging the elements to the top of the empty `divs`. Just because you are changing the background color and min-height doesn't mean the actual sortable's height is changing. So it may look like you can place the items any where in the open area, in reality you actually can't,  unless you define heights for the sortables on the get go.

Comment: good idea @Jack let me see if I can recreate the issue there (-8

Comment: **sorry** it's here: http://jsfiddle.net/jordanbaucke/MMyP3/3/ : try dragging the elements into the empty location without touching a non-empty sortable list, and drop. Nothing happens, it reverts to its original list... now: try to drag-over a non-empty list, and back to the empty one and drop - magically it works!!

Comment: now I see, some minimum height must have already been applied at the time the `.sortable` is attached. adding a `min-height` class to the empty elements definitely gives me a good target area. Still not as visually appealing as having them shrink and expand on hover - but I think I can work my away around that.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your answer so it'll persist after the jsfiddle link rots.

Answer (score 3):

@Jack's explanation of why you can't drop into empty sortables is correct. Sortable caches the positions of its sortables at the beginning of a drag start before any callbacks have been run. So if you change the height of the drop zones in the callback, those are ignored as it still uses cached values.

If you use the Sortable's ['refreshPositions' method](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#method-refreshPositions) just after you adjust the height in your callback, the sortable should now have accurate positioning info so that you can successfully drop in the target zone without having to touch a non-empty sortable list.

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
    start: function (e, ui) {
        $('.sortable_drop_zone').css('min-height', '50px');
        $('#sortable').sortable('refreshPositions');
    }
});
```